# Replace string but keep number (Visual Studio Code)

Tags: visual-studio-code

I need to change some variable declarations that look like:

```
VARCHAR2(...)
```

With ... beeing some number (one, two or three digits). End result should look like:

```
VARCHAR2(... char)
```

Important is, that the number has to bee kept. 
Example:

```
VARCHAR2(20) --> VARCHAR2(20 char)
```

sed or awk are also options but Visual Studio Code would be preferred.

Thanks in advance

Markus

Answer (score 1):

Click on Edit->Replace or <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>

and use the following regular expression for find:

```
(VARCHAR2[(]\d+)([)])
```

and

```
$1 char$2
```

for replace. Of course, the use of regular expressions (the `.*` symbol in the find line) has to be turned on (<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

`(VARCHAR2\(\d{1,3})\)`  replace with

```
$1 char)
```